# Show bundle render options when coding (Style.Render-Script.render)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper

So I’m starting with mvc and I find hard to remember the name of my bundles. When using visual studio it seems easier to just drag and drop the script I need instead of going to my app_start folder and check the name of my bundle.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to show my bundles when I write Styles.Render.

I’m using reshaper too but no option is showed.
Here is an example.
Seems easier to drag and drop my script/style:

[image: draganddrop]

Than writing @styles.render() because it won’t show my bundles so I have to go to my app_start folder and copy-paste it (What I actually do).

If there is an easier way please let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: Normally you'd create a `_layout.cs` that imports the styles for post pages, that solves most of your issues, since you only have to do it once. Then what I normally do is create a bundle config for a specific page that has the same name as the controller or view (easy to remember) which has the page specific styles and scripts. The Bundle Config is where I set this up. Resharper (8.1) does help me when selecting paths from my bundle configuration.

Comment: ty for your answer. it is totally true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'd create a _layout.cs that imports the styles for most pages, that solves most of your issues, since you only have to do it once. Then what I normally do is create a bundle config for a specific page that has the same name as the controller or view (easy to remember) which has the page specific styles and scripts. The Bundle Config is where I set this up. Resharper (8.1) does help me when selecting paths from my bundle configuration.